# Validating data integrity after import from xls to R using RODBC

Tags: r, corrupt, rodbc

I am using RODBC for importing a xls file with ~10000 row and ~250 columns, using the script below:

```
channel <- odbcConnectExcel(xls.file="s:/demo.xls")
demo <- sqlFetch(channel,"Sheet_1")
odbcClose(channel)
```

During the import process, I have open and closed that xls file.

As a precaution, I checked the number of rows from R and from the xls file itself, just to make sure the import is not corrupted, and yup, the number of rows remain the same, so I assume the import process is OK.

Problem arise when I start tabulating the data, I realize that even the row numbers are the same, some rows are actually being corrupted, I have an `UID` inside, and realize that at the later part of the dataframe, the UID are messed up (e.g. same row being duplicated twice).

I re-import the file again, dare not open or close the xls file, and this time, things are going well.

I have learned my lesson of never open or close the xls file when it is being read by RODBC, but how can I be sure that the data will be not messed up, or to ensure that I have really imported the dataset without error, after it is imported?

Thanks.

P.S. I am thinking of exporting the dataframe to csv, and the xls to csv also, then to compare the checksum, as an extra measure, but is there any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

I use the `read.xls` function from the `gdata` package (install using `install.packages(gdata)').

This allows you to read from a non-opened Excel file if I'm correct. It is a wrapper for some Perl modules, so it might depend on whether you have those installed if it works for you.

Quoting the [R manual for Data Export/Import](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html#index-read_002exls-179):

> Perl users have contributed a module OLE::SpreadSheet::ParseExcel and a program xls2csv.pl to convert Excel 95–2003 spreadsheets to CSV files. Package gdata provides a basic wrapper in its read.xls function. With suitable Perl modules installed this function can also read Excel 2007 spreadsheets.

Generally, I find the safest way to get data from Excel into R is via a csv export.